# Form on submit with 2 events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a global function to add a loading effect to my submit buttons in my forms :

```
// add loading effet for forms
$('form').not('.form-ajax').on('submit', function() {
    btnLoad($(this).find('button[type="submit"]'));
});
```

It just shows a loader on the submit button, and disable it.

It works, but sometimes I want to show confirm before submitting :

```
<form method="post" 
    action="/delete/post"
    onsubmit="return confirm('Do you want to delete this post ?');"
>
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="id" />
    <button type="submit">
        Delete post
    </button>
</form>
```

So it shows the loader on my button, but the form is not submitting if the user click no on confirm dialog.

Can I catch it easily ? To show loader on if form is really submitted ?

Comment: I would build the confirmation into the same jQuery submit handler, then handle all of the logic in one place.

Comment: Yes agree, but I have different forms with different onsubmit confirm messages. Maybe yes, I will use a data- attribute and catch it. Thanks I'll try

Answer (score 1):

it'll help u:

```
  <form method="post" 
        action="/delete/post"
        onsubmit="return validate(this);"
    >
        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="id" />
        <button type="submit">
            Delete post
        </button>
    </form>
    <script>
    function validate(form) {

        // validation code here ...


        if(!valid) {
            alert('Please correct the errors in the form!');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');
        }
    }
    </script>
```